# Git-related error message when trying to create an AVD

Tags: android

I was trying to create a new AVD using the ADK and AVD manager and chose to pick the file myself. While navigating to the directory of my choice in the file chooser I saw a flurry of "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" in the console from which I had started the AVD manager and finally "SD Card path isn't valid" in the manager GUI (an error message for which there isn't a single Google match, incidentally).

So far I haven't come across anything in the docs to suggest that Git has anything to do with AVDs, so this is really puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the message on Google. It points me to the source code where this error is launched.

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-sdk/com/android/sdkuilib/internal/widgets/AvdCreationDialog.java.htm

I understand this means the file has to exist (I created an empty one). That made the error message go away.

Comment: Well, back when I posted this there was no match. OK, so the SD Card path and the Git errors are unrelated but that still doesn't explain the Git errors.